# Swapping Timestamp for Timestamp With Time zone causes error with jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm looking for a way around an unexpected problem.  We have a third party app that is loading data into our database.  It's our code that creates the postgresql schema, the third party doesn't provide it.  With  `TIMESTAMP` columns this works, but we'd much prefer to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

We tried to do this by changing the default TimeZone of the user.  The following SQL works through psql.  The fixed timezone for the user is assumed:

```
     insert into AAA (FOO,BAR) select 'X','2022/03/19 21:15:25'  where not exists (select 1  from AAA where FOO = 'X'
```

But the app is raising an exception:

```
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "BAR" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

---

The timezone of the user was set with:

```
insert into pg_db_role_setting  (setrole, setdatabase, setconfig) values (16394, 0, '{TimeZone=+10}')
```

And in psql, subsiquent calls to `SELECT now()` return in `+10` timezone as desired.

---

Firstly, **why could JDBC be hitting an error when the psql doesn't on the same insert statement?**

Secondly is there any workaround for this **without** changing the program source code?

Comment: You accidentally use a parameter of type `character varying`. To be able to say more, we would have to see the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Why do you change the data type in a database of an application over which you don't have any control? If you are suffering from a closed source application, you'll have to ask the vendor who has the code. Nobody else can do more than guess.

Comment: I understand that `timestamp with time zone` is the better choice here, but with the little information we have, we cannot advise how the problem could be solved.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The interesting point is the difference between jdbc behaviour and console. I imagine that someone might know why a JDBC parameterised SQL call could coerce types differently with JDBC vs psql console **for the same query**. While it's frustrating to not have source code, I suspect someone might know something useful even without it